# How can I change the login display resolution on fedora?

Tags: fedora, resolution

I have installed Fedora 31, but the login screen has another display resolution than my working desktop. How can I change the resolution of my login screen?

Comment: Try setting it in grub: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution